# Initial values in django forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-formwizard

Hello People here is my code

```
class F1articles(forms.Form):
  heading=forms.CharField(max_length=100)
  content=forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
class F2articles(forms.Form):
  country=forms.CharField(max_length=100)
  work=forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

this is in Urls.py

```
url(r'^create/(?P<project_id>\d+)/$', FarticlesWizard.as_view([F1articles, F2articles]))
```

this is my view

```
class FarticlesWizard(SessionWizardView):
def done(self,form_list,**kwargs):
    form_dict={}
    Varticles_obj=None

    for x in form_list:
        form_dict=dict(form_dict.items()+x.cleaned_data.items())

    if kwargs.has_key('project_id'):
        Varticles_obj=Marticles.objects.get(id=kwargs['project_id'])
        Varticles_obj.heading=form_dict['heading']
        Varticles_obj.content=form_dict['content']
        Varticles_obj.country=form_dict['country']
        Varticles_obj.work=form_dict['work']
        Varticles_obj.modified_on=datetime.datetime.now()
        Varticles_obj.modified_by=self.request.user.username
        Varticles_obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/display/')
    else:       
        insert_db=Marticles(heading = form_dict['heading'],
        content = form_dict['content'],
          country=form_dict['country'],work=form_dict['work'],created_by=self.request.user)
        insert_db.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/display/')
```

this works fine with no issues but i want to set initial values to form fields when the url is called,, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Hi Rohan,question updated,,,, please check,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmmm i got it working,Let me answer my own question,..here is the code ...

```
    def get_form_initial(self,step):

    if 'project_id' in self.kwargs:
        project_id=self.kwargs['project_id']
        article=Marticles.objects.get(id=project_id)
        project_dict = model_to_dict(article)
        return project_dict
    else:
        return self.initial_dict.get(step,{})
```

I think this will be helpfull for you guyzz...

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `WizardView.get_form_initial(step)` method to provide initial data for each step of the wizard.

Something like:

```
class FarticlesWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def get_form_initial(self, step):
        init_dict = {}
        #get object to populate data
        if step == '1':
            init_dict = { 'heading': obj.heading, 'content' : obj.content }
        if step == '2':
            init_dict = { 'country': obj.country, 'work' : obj.work }

        return init_dict
```

I'm not sure how would you get `project_id` in this method from url to query the object.

Comment: Hi Rohan,I tried your method  but iam getting an error `get_form_initial() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)` and iam getting project id from here `kwargs['project_id']`

Comment: @Friend, it should take `self` parameter as well, check updated definition.

Comment: Hi Rohan, i tried your method ,it did not take intial values but the form with empty data was shown, and also got an error while submiting `FarticlesWizard class has not defined a done() method, which is required`

Comment: @Friend, didn't you have `done()` method in your view, as you have in question?

Comment: hi rohan,thanks alot for trying,i got it working now,i have posted the answer ....